# Calculation method used by MS Windows' powercfg/batteryreport

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, laptop

I'm working on the efficiency of laptops chargers, and I want to estimate it *without* damaging cables if possible.

Therefore, I had the idea to use MS Windows powercfg tool, that provides us the energy stored in the battery as shown in the picture below, for the DC-side of the chargers.

[image: energy report generated with MS Windows' powercfg tool]

My problem is that I don't know how powercfg calculates these values, and I couldn't find more info on the Internet (perhaps I did't use the good keywords).

Does anyone have an idea of how this calculation is performed ?

Comment: The program asks the info from motherboard battery interface of some sorts, the program doesn't calculate anything. How the battery interface calculates it will be unknown unless you know what chipset your pack has for coulomb counting. But it has nothing to do with efficiency of the charger. The laptop itself consumes current from the power supply. And you could use an extension adapter for measuring so you don't have to damage existing cables.

Comment: Okay thank you for this answer =)
I have too many different computers to analyze, i'll look for an adapter !

Comment: Why not just plug the laptop to be tested into a [Kill-A-Watt](https://www.google.com/search?q=kill-a-watt) or something similar?

Comment: @brhans the aim of the study is to know the efficiency of the AC-DC power supplies of the laptops. We will plug them into such a device to measure the power it consumes from the grid, but we also need to know the power transmitted from the supply to the laptop at the DC side, and then analyze the difference between those two values

Comment: Then you're going to have to open up the charger if you hope to get results which are even close to accurate. Power coming in to the laptop from the charger goes 2 ways - to the battery to charge it, and to the rest of motherboard to actually run the laptop. Those powercfg reports don't tell you how much power is being used to run the laptop.